# Flutter: OrientationBuilder - reuse child widgets without rebuilding?

Tags: flutter, widget, reusability, device-orientation

I am using OrientationBuilder to define portrait and landscape layouts. The layout includes two widgets for example: a TextField widget and GoogleMap widget. In 'Portrait' the layout utilises a TabBarView to move between the two widgets horizontally. In 'Landscape' the widgets are placed side by side on the screen in Expanded Containers.

If I update the TextField in portrait and change to landscape the data is lost. I can manage this with a variable and this is quick and easy. If however I rebuild the Map which may have moved and had hundreds of markers and lines added etc I have to redraw each marker every time the user changes the device orientation. Whilst this is achievable the redraw takes considerable time when hundreds of markers and lines are present.

The question is then, is it possible to reuse the widgets across the orientation change including any user added markers, lines etc without rebuilding each every time? Ie something similar to AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin like we use for TabBar shifts? Or am I tackling this the wrong way?

Example

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test ({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TestState createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test > {
  TestState({Key key});
  Widget mMap;
  Widget mText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    mMap = gMap();
    mText = gText();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        return orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? portraitLayout()
            : landscapeLayout();
      },
    );
  }

  Widget portraitLayout() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: TabBarView(
            //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              gText(),
              gMap(),
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget landscapeLayout() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: gText(),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: gMap()
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextField gText() {
    return TextField();
  }

  GoogleMap gMap() {
    return GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(37.0, -122.0),
        zoom: 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After much effort and testing multiple options I concluded that the two layouts in orientation builder are entirely separate and never the twain shall meet. As a workaround in this particular case then I discarded orientation builder and instead created a row with two expanded widgets both of width 0 and updated the flex based upon the device orientation. eg in portrait, flex of 1 (show) and 0 (hide) with say a floating action bar to reverse as needed, and in landscape flex of 1 and 1 to display both equally. Might not be the right way but its simple and may be of interest to someone else one day.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      formFlex = 1;
      mapFlex = 1;
    }
    else if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait && formFlex==mapFlex){
      formFlex = 1;
      mapFlex = 0;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: getAppBar(),
      body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex:formFlex,
              child: Container(width: 0, child: Text('Test1')),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex:mapFlex,
              child: Container(width: 0, child: gMap()),
            )
          ]
      ),
    );
  }
```